# Is it possible to create an s3 uploader instance at the same time as a regular fine uploader instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am using fine uploader in two ways but all in one process.  I have pdf files that I split and merge and do that locally using a basic fine uploader instance.  When I'm done I want to upload each merged file to our amazon s3 bucket.  I have two instances of the fine uploader in the same javascript file.  However, the s3 instance is giving an error as it is being defined in a jquery wrapper.

The process for this page includes the following:

1. User selects the upload button on the first uploader to upload a
       pdf file
2. a modal pops up to allow the user to select whether to
       upload the file as is or split out the pdf file into separate pages
        if the user selects to upload as is... s3 bucket fine uploader is
       invoked (not working now);  if the user selects to split the pdf
       files, another modal pops up after the files are split and shows the
       individual pages for the user to reorganize by document type.
3. after reorganizing the pdf pages into separate doc types, they are merged
       into new pdf files.
4. as each merged file is completed, I want to upload that file to the s3 bucket for that user.  This is where the second uploader instance need to be invoked to add the files and then upload the files.

Here are the error messages I'm receiving in the javascript console (using Chrome) when the user selects the first upload button:

```
VM33414:16 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined**
qq.basePublicApi.getUuid @ VM33414:16
qq.basePrivateApi._onSubmitDelete @ VM33414:17
qq.uiPrivateApi._onSubmitDelete @ VM33414:18
qq.basePublicApi.deleteFile @ VM33414:16
(anonymous function) @ VM33416:224
b.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
v.handle @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
VM33416:157 

merged file: /var/www/html/ajax/common/files/044da577-e054-407a-95a5-aaa17899897b/1_TestDoc5_W9.pdf
VM33416:165 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fineUploaderS3 is not a function
jQuery.ajax.success @ VM33416:165
c @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
p.fireWith @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
k @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
r @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
VM33416:157 

merged file: /var/www/html/ajax/common/files/044da577-e054-407a-95a5-aaa17899897b/1_TestDoc5_License.pdf
VM33416:165 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fineUploaderS3 is not a function
jQuery.ajax.success @ VM33416:165
c @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
p.fireWith @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
k @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
r @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
VM33416:157 

merged file: /var/www/html/ajax/common/files/044da577-e054-407a-95a5-aaa17899897b/1_TestDoc5_Other.pdf
VM33416:165 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fineUploaderS3 is not a function
```

Here is my script file:

```
var thisArray=[];
var pdfoptions=[];
var mydate = new Date();
var month = mydate.getMonth() + 1 ;
var today = month + '/' + mydate.getDate() + '/' +  mydate.getFullYear();

//s3 instance
$('#s3-uploader').fineUploaderS3({
    debug: true,
    autoUpload: false,
    uploaderType: 'basic',
    request: {
        endpoint: 'rog-zone.s3.amazonaws.com',
        accessKey:'################'
    },
    objectProperties: {
        // Since we want all items to be publicly accessible w/out a server to return a signed URL
        acl: "public-read"
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: "/assets/plugins/fine-uploader/signature/endpoint.php"
    },
    validation: {
        itemLimit: 5,
        sizeLimit: 15000000
    }
    }).on('submit', function (event,id, name) {
        console.log("[on submit] id:"+id+ " and name:"+name);
         return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            resolve();
         });
    }).on('complete', function(event,id,fileName,responseJSON,xhr){
            console.log("[on complete]:"+id+ " and filename:"+fileName);
            var $fileEl = $(this).fineUploaderS3("getItemByFileId", id);            

    }).on('upload', function(event, id, name, isError,responseJSON) {
            var obj = JSON.stringify(responseJSON);
            console.log("[on Upload] id:"+id+ " and response = "+obj);
    }
);


//manual file uploader for local processing.  WHen done, upload merged file to s3 bucket
var manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader"),
        template: 'qq-template-manual',
        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: "/ajax/common/endpoint.php"
        },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: true,
            endpoint: "/ajax/common/endpoint.php"
        },
        chunking: {
            enabled: true
        },
        resume: {
            enabled: true
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: true,
            showButton: true
        },
        callbacks: {
            onUpload: function (id, name) {
                console.log("onUpload");
            },
            onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
                console.log("onComplete >> id:"+id+ "; filename:"+fileName+"; folder:"+responseJSON.uuid);
                var uuid = responseJSON.uuid;
                $("#splitter_uuid").val(uuid);
                var filetosplit = uuid+"/"+fileName;
                var imgsrc = 'ajax/common/files/'+uuid+'/';
                var fileinfo = fileName.split(".");
                var fileprefix = fileinfo[0];
                $("#splitter_filename").val(fileName);

                jQuery('#pdfHandler').modal();
                jQuery('#btnUploadPDF').click(function () {
                    return true;
                });
                jQuery('#btnSplitPDF').click(function (e) {
                    jQuery.ajax({url: "http://52.11.64.64/ajax/common/pdfsplitter.php?pdf="+filetosplit,
                        success: function(result){
                            //console.log("result from ajax:"+result);
                            jQuery("#pagecounttext").text("There are "+result+" pages to split.  Please indicate how you would like to organize these files below.");
                            for (i=1;i<=result;i++){
                                var imgfile = fileprefix+'_'+i+'.jpg';
                                var pdfpage = '<a href="#" class="btn pdf-page text-inverse p-0" data-page-id="'+i+'"><img class="imgsplit" src="'+imgsrc+imgfile+'" height=90 border="1"><a/>';
                                //<i class="btl bt-file bt-3x"></i>
                                jQuery("#pdfpages").append(pdfpage);
                            }
                            //show modal where user selects how to organize pages with document type
                            $("#pdfSplitter").modal("show");
                            //add pages selected to document type
                            jQuery('a.pdf-page').on('click',function(e){
                                e.preventDefault();
                                var thisPageID=jQuery(this).data("page-id");
                                thisArray.push(thisPageID);
                                thisArray.sort();
                                jQuery(this).attr("disabled",true);
                                jQuery('#pdfSplitterTable tr.active td input').val(thisArray);                              
                                //save selections in local array since this element does not seem to persist to when it is needed
                                var thisoption = jQuery("#pdfSplitterTable tr.active td select").val();


                            });     

                            jQuery('#btnAddDocumentRow').on('click',function(e){
                                e.preventDefault();
                                var originalSelID=jQuery('#pdfSplitterTable tr.original td select').attr('id');
                                var pdfSplitterTableLen=jQuery('#pdfSplitterTable tr').length;
                                jQuery('#pdfSplitterTable tr').removeClass('active');
                                jQuery('#pdfSplitterTable tr:last').clone().insertAfter('#pdfSplitterTable tr:last');
                                jQuery('#pdfSplitterTable tr:last').removeClass();
                                jQuery('#pdfSplitterTable tr:last').addClass('active');
                                jQuery('#pdfSplitterTable tr:last td input').val('');
                                jQuery('#pdfSplitterTable tr:last td select').attr('id',originalSelID+pdfSplitterTableLen);
                                jQuery('#pdfSplitterTable tr:last td select').attr('name',originalSelID+pdfSplitterTableLen);
                                jQuery("select[name='"+originalSelID+pdfSplitterTableLen+"']").val(0);
                                jQuery("select[name='"+originalSelID+pdfSplitterTableLen+"']").change();    
                                thisArray=[];
                            });                                             
                    }});
                    return true;                        
                });

            },
            onSubmit: function(id,name){
                var fileExtension = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toUpperCase();
                if(fileExtension==='PDF'){                    
                    //jQuery('#pdfHandler').modal();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert("Please select a PDF file");
                    return false;
                }
            },
            onSubmitted: function (id, name) {
                //console.log("onSubmitted");                
            }
        }
    });

$( document ).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#btnUploadPDF,#btnSplitPDF').on('click',function(e){
        jQuery('#clickfrom').val('nav-tabs');
    });

    jQuery('#btnSplitPDF').on ('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    jQuery("#btnUploadFiles").on('click',function(e){
        var uuid = jQuery("#splitter_uuid").val();
        var filename = jQuery("#splitter_filename").val();
        var userid = jQuery("#splitter_userid").val();

        jQuery("#pdfSplitterTable td select").each(function() {
            var option = jQuery(this).val();
            var pageids = jQuery(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val();
            console.log("pageids: "+pageids+" and option="+option);//test this
            //add new item to table of documents for user
            var lastclass = jQuery("#document-checklist tr").last().attr("class");
            var newclass = 'even';
            if (lastclass=='even'){newclass = 'odd';}
            jQuery("#document-checklist tbody")
                .append('<tr class="'+newclass+'"><td>'+option
                +'</td><td>Pending Review</td><td></td><td>'+today
                +'</td><td></td><td></td><td><a href="#"></a><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></a></td></tr>');      
            //console.log("merge files: "+JSON.stringify(pdfoptions));                  

            jQuery.ajax({url: "http://52.11.64.64/ajax/common/pdfmerge.php?pdf="+filename+"&uuid="+uuid+"&pageids="+pageids+"&option="+option+"&userid="+userid,
                success: function(mergedfile){
                    //result is new merged filename to upload
                    console.log("merged file: "+mergedfile);

                    //HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO UPLOAD TO S3
                    jQuery("#s3-uploader").fineUploaderS3('addFiles',mergedfile);
                    jQuery("#s3-uploader").fineUploaderS3('uploadStoredFiles');             
                }
            });     
        });

        manualUploader.deleteFile();    
    });

});//doc ready
```

Thank You,
Cindy

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Fine Uploader endpoint handlers may be defined and leveraged within one HTML document. In order to do this, however, the jQuery plugin cannot be used due to namespace conflicts. In fact the jQuery plugin (wrapper) has been on the roadmap for [full removal for quite some time](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1310).

You will most likely want to leverage the [multiple server type "Windows Azure + Amazon S3 + Traditional" download](http://fineuploader.com/customize.html) to integrate both the Traditional and Amazon S3 endpoint handers on the page. This will require you to define the Amazon S3 endpoint handler with traditional JavaScript syntax (which is actually a bit simpler):

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploaderBasic({
    debug: true,
    autoUpload: false,
    request: {
        endpoint: 'rog-zone.s3.amazonaws.com',
        accessKey:'################'
    },
    objectProperties: {
        // Since we want all items to be publicly accessible w/out a server to return a signed URL
        acl: "public-read"
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: "/assets/plugins/fine-uploader/signature/endpoint.php"
    },
    validation: {
        itemLimit: 5,
        sizeLimit: 15000000
    },
    callbacks: {
        onSubmit: function(id, name) {
            console.log("[on submit] id:" + id + " and name:" + name);
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                resolve();
            });
        },
        onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON, xhr){
            console.log("[on complete]:" + id + " and filename:" + fileName);
            var fileEl = this.getItemByFileId(id);              
        },
        onUpload: function(id, name, isError, responseJSON) {
            var obj = JSON.stringify(responseJSON);
            console.log("[on Upload] id:" + id + " and response = " + obj);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You, Dan.  As of now, I've moved on to create a local upload first since I had to some file splitting and merging before uploading to my s3 bucket.  So now I am onl\y using one instance of the s3 bucket to simply upload files after being processed locally.  Cindy